# Define a DFA for the language $L_n$

Tags: computer-science, automata

> Let $L_n=\{w\in\{0,1\}^* \mid  \text{ the } n^{\text{th}}\text{ from  last  character  is } 1\}$.
>
> Define a DFA for this language, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> - Hint: consider a binary word in length $n$.

---

$Solution.$ Let $$A=(Q,\Sigma,q_0,\delta,F)$$ be the DFA for $L_n$.

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$, then: $$Q=\{q_0,q_1,\dots,q_{n+m}\}$$
$$F=\{q_{n+m}\}$$
and let $\displaystyle \delta :( Q\times \Sigma )\rightarrow Q$,  such that:

$$\forall i\in[1,n+m+1] \backslash\{q_m\}:\delta(q_{i-1},\sigma)=q_i$$
$$\delta(q_{m-1},1)=q_m$$
$$\delta(q_{m-1},0)=q_{pit}$$

---

Now, I know that defining $m$ it's not good of what I heard. Therefore, I will
be glad to know if it isn't correct to define $m$, and how can I solve it by using only $n$?

Thanks!

Comment: It is totally unclear, what $m$ is. In particular your DFA must not depend on the length of the word it gets.

Comment: @user940347 so can I define $m$ to depend on the length of the word I get? because then I can write that $m$ is the length of the word I get minus $n$

Comment: No! You must not do that. I'm currently writing an answer with an suitable DFA

Comment: I would write a NFA, which is pretty much direct, and then transform it into a DFA with the standard algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose $Q = \{0,1\}^{\le n}$, the set of strings consiting of $0$ and $1$ of length at most $n$, including the empty string $\emptyset$.

The informal interpretation of this (which then gives the idea how to define the rest of the DFA) is: You interpret these states as storing the last $n$ digits you have read up to now (or less then $n$, if you have been reading less than $n$ digitis up to now).

Hence, your initial position is $q_0 = \emptyset$ (you haven't read anything up to now).

Your accepting set is $F = \{ 1a : a \in \{0,1\}^{n-1} \}$, i.e. all strings of length $n$ where the first digit is 1. (Since your states are indetend to represent exactlythe $n$-th last digits of your string, this exactly says that the $n$-th last digit is $1$)

The transition function $\delta : Q \times \{0,1\} \to Q$ is "writing the digit you read to the end of the string and forget the first digit, if it would get longer than $n$". That means $\delta(a,x) = ax$, if $a \in \{0,1\}^{\le n-1}$ and $x \in \{0,1\}$. And $\delta(a,x)=a_2\dots a_nx$, if $a =(a_1\dots a_n) \in \{0,1\}^n$ and $x \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: but $a$ isn't a state, it's a word. How can you define this $\delta$ like that?

Comment: $a$ is as state because we defined the set of states as the set of all words of length at most $n$. Note: do not confuse that with the input word your DFA reads!

Comment: Ok, but how it does what you said? I mean, how he can read $m$ words, then proceed with $n$ chars?

Comment: What is this strange $m$ ?! It appears neither in the task nor in my solution...

Comment: If for example you want to read $w=\sigma_1\sigma_2\dots \sigma_m 1 \sigma_{n+1} \dots \sigma_{n+m}$...

Comment: I think you mean $w=\sigma_1\sigma_2\dots \sigma_m 1 \sigma_{m+2} \dots \sigma_{m+n}$ ? (i.e. a "general" element of $L_n$)

Comment: Right, and then I can depend on $m$... that's what I was trying to do in my solution.

Comment: Ok, i.e. $m$ is just "length of the word minus $n$"... Then $w$ will be accepted. You will be in the states $\emptyset$ then  $\sigma_1$ then $\sigma_1\sigma_2$ at some point in   $\sigma_1 \dots \sigma_n$, then in $\sigma_2 \dots \sigma_{n+1}$ an eventually in the accepting state $1\sigma_{m+2} \dots \sigma_{m+n}$.

Comment: yes, and that is exactly what I did. Why can't I define such $m$?

Comment: If your DFA depends on $m$, it depends on the length of the word and (as I said at the very beginning) a DFA is not allowed to depend on the length of the word that it's currently reading

Comment: then I can't understand how your solution saves each char read already?

Comment: It doesn't. No DFA can do that, because a DFA is a finite object and can only store finitely many information. The crucial point is that is forgets everything up to the last $n$ digits, because they are irrelevant for decideing if your word is in $L_n$. (and $n$ is a fixed parameter from the task!)

Comment: Oh, I see! but what in your solution tells that we have reached the $n^{th}$ char from last?

Comment: The definition of accepting a word is that the state in your in, when being at the end of the word is in $F$. By my definition of $\delta$ the state is always the last $n$ digits your read, hence at the end the state is exactly the last $n$ digits of the whole word. Now, my definition of $F$ says "the state has to be a string of length $n$ starting with 1", i.e. the $n$-th last digit is a 1.

Comment: I got you, thanks!